# convert postscript file to eps file that is in a vector format

Tags: postscript, eps

I want to generate an eps file (.eps) that contains vector data rather than rasterized data. I am trying to do so by converting a postscript file (.ps) into an eps file using ps2eps like so:

```
ps2eps asdf.ps
```

However this results in a rasterized output. Why is this? How can I get a non rasterized output?

here is the content of the asdf.ps file:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 400 400

% Draw a line
1 setlinewidth
0 0 moveto
200 200 lineto
0 0 1 setrgbcolor
stroke

% Draw a circle
100 100 40 0 360 arc
1 setlinewidth
0 0 0 setrgbcolor
1 setgray
fill
stroke
```

Comment: Asking the same question multiple times isn't going to win you points. PostScript (and therefore EPS) may contain raster data. If the PostScript contains raster data, so will any EPS created from it. If you want to 'generate an eps file' that contains vector data, then don't start with rasters. I'm pretty sure I answered this elsewhere and told you that you'd need to start by turning the raster into vecctor using some other tool.

Comment: my original postscript file doesn't contain any raster content. I'll modify the OP to make this more clear

Comment: When I run your (already identified as EPS) program through current Ghostscript (10.02.0) using : "gs -sDEVICE=eps2write -o out.eps test.ps" the resulting EPS file does not contain rasterised output. I've no idea what program ps2eps is if it isn't a script to run Ghostscript and you haven't said if you are using Ghostscript and if so, which version.